# How to find "nice" partial fraction decompositions

Tags: algebraic-manipulation

This is similar to one of my previous questions [How to factorize polynomials into "shortest possible" pieces](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/143766/35000) -- unfortunately I do not have any rigorous formulations of what I want to achieve. But here is an example that I encountered:

[image]

```
Apart[(1+2 x+x^2-3 x^3-9 x^4-4 x^5)/((1-x) (1-3 x^2)^2)]
```

produces

[image]

At the same time the expression is equal to

```
(1+2 x^2)/((1-x) (1-2 x^2) )+(2 x(1+2 x))/( (1-2 x^2)(1-3 x^2))+(x^2 (1+2 x)^2)/(1-3 x^2)^2
```

[image]

which is much nicer (well, at least for my purposes).

Is there a way to explain to Mathematica that I want such form?

Comment: A first step would be to operationalize what you mean by "'nice' partial fraction decomposition".

Comment: A next step would be to provide examples as text (rather than images).

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Sorry I should remember this. Done

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I am reluctant to write this into the question since I am not entirely sure what I mean. Let us try like this: a sum of fractions where each numerator and denominator is a product of monomials or binomials like `cx^n` or `1-cx^n`,  difference between degrees of denominator and numerator is as large as possible, and moreover each `c` is rational with as small numerator and denominator as possible

Comment: I'll be curious to see what comes up. I suspect this is a difficult problem. Especially if term denominators can contain factors not in the original one.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Exhaustive search over very limited amount of candidate forms already grows the search space to billions of candidates. One could try to formulate the search in interesting ways, such as a constrained vector subset sum problem (over $N$ values of $x$), but considering complexity of those problems, I wouldn't hold high hopes...